# Best 'SNR-like' detection statistic for time series signal in the wavelet domain?

Tags: wavelet, signal-detection, snr, time-series, discrete-wavelet-transform

What is the best way to define a detection statistic for a time series event trigger generator, which computes the wavelet transform of some time series data? I want such quantity to be similar to a blind SNR, but based on wavelet coefficients.

Comment: "Best" depends on some metric for "good", right? But you haven't told us what the thing is that you want to optimize, so we can't tell you. What is it that you want to do with that statistic?

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller , I want a quantity which I can use to characterise an event (such as a short burst signal) which allows me to set a threshold similarly to a SNR, or an SNR reweighed on noise background. i.e. I want to be able to characterise a "loud" signal.

Comment: You said so. What for? The metric you choose depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the goal is signal detection. Specifically I want to build a Receiver-operating characteristic (ROC) curve computing false alarm rates (FAR) in coloured noise, where noise or signal bursts can modify the PSD locally. I have the assumption of stationary gaussian noise background. I want to build ROC at different "wavelet SNR" cuts. I can add this to the question.

Comment: Ah, so a metric that grows with the probability that something contains a signal and falls with the probability it only contains noise; I honestly should have read that from your wording "detection statistic", my mistake, sorry. I assume your noise is uncorrelated/white?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, sorry I wasn't too clear. The background noise is originally not white, but follows a specific stationary PSD in frequency domain. I do whiten the data, so I assume the noise background is white when I run the wavelet transform. "Events" will be of two types: noise burst, signal burst.

Comment: But then you're probably already doing the right thing! If noise is white and uncorrelated with signal, and your wavelet transform does sufficiently many summations per bin, then the noise will be normally distributed in each bin. You doing a wavelet transform implicitly assumes that, however, signal had components that are linearly dependent on your wavelet base, so that in the presence of signal, your bins are *not* normally distributed. Great! You can now find a way to calculate the probability that the observed distribution of bin values comes from a gaussian pdf, and use that as metric

Comment: (or that the absolute value follows Rayleigh, out the square $\chi^2$, or you don't calculate the probability but the logarithm or the exponential function of that - whatever makes your math easiest)